# IE 11 - TLS Error for only the one user login in a Windows 10 profile, that works fine with my own email

Tags: windows-10, office365, tls, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

I have reviewed other IE11 TLS fixes and not had any success, perhaps I've missed something from them...

When we are in IE 11 and launching our Sharepoint website, it leads as usual to our Office 365 login page, asking for an email address.

Now if we enter my users email and continue, instead of going to our fs.company.com login page it leads to a TLS error and we cannot get past it.

However, if I enter my own email instead of my users and continue, the page goes right past the TLS error and shows the normal password login page.

Further, if we instead use IE11 InPrivate browsing and enter my users email it takes us to the next login page as well and allows sign in.

I have had IE closed and launched inetcpl.cpl to reset the IE caches and have Not preserved favorites.

All the TLS permutations have been tried I think.  Enabled mixed content is on.

I have opened the IE appdata folder and deleted everything there manually.

Chrome and new Edge work instantly.  However we need IE11 to work for a little while longer.

If feels at this point like there is an old certificate that just won't go away that is tied to her login.

This all seemed to happen after my user reset their password a few days ago.

Im open to any and all suggestions at this point and appreciate any thoughts you may want to share on it.